# Getting wrong translation from Google translate using C#

Tags: c#, google-translate, translate

I was using this method to translate some text from my program using google translate, this was working perfectly until this week:

```
public string TranslateText(string input, string languagePair)
        {
            string r = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(input);
            r = WebUtility.UrlEncode(r);
            string url = String.Format("http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", r, languagePair);
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
            byte[] resultbyte = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            string result = Encoding.Default.GetString(resultbyte);
            result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("TRANSLATED_TEXT=") + 16);
            result = result.Replace("\\x26", "&");
            result = result.Replace("\\x3d", "=");
            result = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(result);
            result = result.Remove(result.IndexOf(";"));
            result = result.Replace("'", string.Empty);

            return result;

        }
```

But now I'm running the program just as always and I'm getting this translations always:

```
<html lang="en"> <head> <style>@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?lang=en&family=Product+Sans|Roboto:400,700)
```

And I don´t know what could happen. Anyone knows what's the problem?

Comment: Google probably changed the format of the response

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google implies that the Google Translate API hasn't been designed to work like that for a while, the fact it's lasted that long for you is probably sheer luck.

The way you are using the Google Translate tools is not allowed under their terms (essentially screen scraping their free web tool).  You should [apply for an account](https://console.cloud.google.com/freetrial/signup/0?pli=1) with them and expect to [pay](https://cloud.google.com/translate/pricing), albeit a small amount if you are only translating a little bit of text. You may be able to get around it by modifying your URL and web page scraping code (if you haven't already been blocked), but you can't ask for help here to circumvent legal agreements.

If you decide to go the legal route, once you're up and running with an account you can access the API directly using your API key/token.  See the [quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart) for details.